# Mapbox markers and the centre of the map v marker

Tags: mapbox

[image]

See attached image, I have a Mapbox map and a marker that is "centred in the map", what I want is the marker's point to be at the centre (where the red arrow is) and not the middle of the marker.

the marker is Mapbox, setting the lng lat is Mapbox, getting the centre of the map is Mapbox, does anyone know if Mapbox construct the marker in such a way where the end point is the middle?

if not, is there a way to adjust ?

thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else needing this information

1)
mapbox allows the markers centre to be set when you add the marker, so you can say the centre is top, bottom, centre etc etc
2)
out of the box the mapbox markers are centred in the correct place using "centre". proved this by debugging the GPS from mapbox and comparing to google maps lng,lat and then using every setting to see which one was exactly the same mapping